# NSDate set format to MM/YYYY but result shows dd/YYYY

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a sample code as below and I would like to show in MM/yyyy. However, I get result in dd/yyyy.

```
NSString *strJoinedDate = [prefs stringForKey:@"creation_date"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *JoinedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strJoinedDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/yyyy"];
NSString *strFinalJoinedDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Since %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:JoinedDate]];
```

Comment: Give a few specific examples of `strJoinedDate` and the corresponding `strFinalJoinedDate`. Your code is correct so perhaps the initial string is not what you think.

Comment: strJoinedDate = 5/29/2018 3:23:28 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong date format for a date string such as `5/29/2018 3:23:28 AM`. Change:

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a
```

to:

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a
```

You also need to set the date formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

```
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

Comment: I updated the answer. You also find the following article useful: http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html